# we are trying to save the uploaded file in a local folder by using the angular code

Tags: angular

We are trying to save the uploaded file in the local folder by using the angular code. But we are unable to do this. Did somebody try to do this in angular6 or 7

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the uploaded file to `base64` and then get it downloaded to client system using [FileSaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver/v/1.3.2)

But ideally, the uploaded file should be stored in server folder.